# Sorting MySQL query by a function instead of a column

Tags: mysql

If my website display the products price as the output of a function display_price(), how can I sort the query by price ?

e.g.

> Product A price is 100 and base currency is USD = 100USD 
> Product B
>   price is 95 and base currency is EU = 103USD

Order by price ASC; will list Product B then A, but I use this function to output the correct price:

```
Function display_price($products_price, $currency_value) {
$price = $products['price'] * $products['currency_value'];
return $price;
}
```

How can I sort my query in this situation ?

Thank you

Comment: In general, and without any additional information about what you're describing, sorting in a SQL query is done with the `ORDER BY` clause.  If that's not available to you for some reason or not working in some way, you're going to have to specify the problem.

Comment: Either use the alias of the calculated column or just the function in the ORDER BY clause.

Comment: @David I specified the problem with an example, thanks :)

Comment: @LudwigArcache: Is that SQL code?  Looks like PHP.  Sorting an array in PHP and sorting a query result in SQL are two very different things.  Can you clarify exactly what you're trying to do here?

Comment: @David this is part of the entire code. I cannot include everything in my question. I'm sorting a SQL query not PHP array. but this PHP function serve to display the correct price (USD price). Anyway, thank you, appreciated

Comment: @PaulSpiegel can you tell me how to use the function in the ORDER BY clause ?

Comment: @LudwigArcache: `"I'm sorting a SQL query"` - Then you're looking for the `ORDER BY` clause.  And the code you've posted has nothing to do with it.  You're going to want to look at the actual SQL query, not the PHP code which uses the results of that query.

Answer (score 0):

This implies that you have a simple calculated value in your queried data:

```
$price = $products['price'] * $products['currency_value'];
```

So calculate that value in the query itself, not in PHP.  Assuming the structure of your query, you'd add a calculated column:

```
SELECT
    some_field,
    some_other_field,
    and_so_on,
    price,
    currency_value,
    price * currency_value AS product_price -- add the calculated value
FROM
    some_table
ORDER BY
    product_price -- sort by the calculated value
```

No need to involve PHP at all.  As far as PHP is concerned, the result of the query includes the values it needs and is in the order it needs to be.

Comment: i have currency_id instead of currency_value. Currency value comes from a class which in turn is related to other functions...

Let us assume I have to involve a PHP function in a ORDER BY clause, is that possible somehow ?

Comment: @LudwigArcache: If you're asking whether you can execute PHP code on MySQL, then no.  As for what options you *do* have, you're going to need to specify information about the problem in the question.  Nobody here knows your database or query structures.